# Removing special character from a string

Tags: php

I want to remove the special character `@` from the following string

```
 $string="Test <a href='/group/profile/1'>@Test User</a> another test <a href='/group/profile/2'>@User Test</a>";
```

Expected output:

```
 <a href='/group/profile/1'>Test User</a> another test <a href='/group/profile/2'>User Test</a>"
```

Here i need to check each anchor tags in the string and need to find only the anchor tags with the word profile in href and need to remove the `@` from the link text.If there is any `@` outside the anchor tag in the string it should not be removed, only the `@` in the anchor tag need to be removed.

Comment: The output is missing the leading `"Test "` as well; expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(<a href.*profile.*>)@/U', '$1', $string);
```

Mind the ungreedy (U) modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$string = <<<EOT

@Do not remove
Test <a href='/group/profile/1'>@Test User</a> another test <a href='/group/profile/2'>@User Test</a>
@metoo

EOT;


$string = preg_replace('/(\<a\s+.+?\>.*?)(\@)(.*?\<\/a\>)/','$1$3',$string);

var_dump($string);
```

This can be buggy on big strings though

https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

//remove @ from string

```
 $string=str_replace('@','',$string);
```

//encode string using base64_encode function of php

```
 $string=base64_encode($string);
```

//decode string using base64_decode function of php

```
echo $string=base64_decode($string);            //Expected output
```